Google Sheets Regex for the inconsistent pattern
Attached are the Inputs and Expected Outputs based on which I wanted a common regex pattern which can be used in Google Sheets:

Example:
In case of following string in a cell:
"30m DEVO-67, DEVO-68
1h DEVO-69, DEVO-70
2h DEVO-75"
Following should be the output:
DEVO-67, DEVO-68, DEVO-69, DEVO-70, DEVO-75
Basically wanted to extract all the DEVO followed by Dash and a number from any given string.
I tried following but it is not working:
=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"[0-9]+\S+\s+DEVO-(\d+).*","DEVO - $1")


Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

It is much easier if you add a function in the Script Editor that can extract multiple matches and join them with any separator of your choice, so that you can simply write =ExtractAllRegex(B1, "DEVO-\d+", 0, ", ")

=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?is).*?(DEVO-\d+)","$1, ")

The idea is to select batches of
"Any unwanted string""DEVO-number"

and replace with
"DEVO-number",

with case insensitive matching and single line mode: (?is)

Try:
=JOIN(", ",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(DEVO-\d+)|.","$1 ")," ")) 

If you want the matches across the row rather than joined together, remove the JOIN:
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(DEVO-\d+)|.","$1 ")," ")


Try this:
=LET(x, REDUCE(,SPLIT(JOIN(" ", SPLIT(A1, CHAR(10))), {" "","}),  LAMBDA(a,c, IF(REGEXMATCH(c, "DEVO"), JOIN(",",a,c),a))), RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-1))

Sample Output


This results some extra i.e. giving the following output for 3rd input case: "DEVO-53
1h,DEVO-52
1h,DEVO-71
2h,DEVO-83"

I revised my answer, please check if this now works for you. Please feel free to comment if you think that this formula needs improvement or this works for you.

Thank you for the updates! But Newline character is not being handled

Can you share with me what do you mean by new line characters I have tested on my end it seems that it is being catered, are referring about expanding this across a range?

I saw what you mean and updated the formula
